# Site has been blocked by Cors policy when I use Nginx of AWS ec2

Tags: reactjs, node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, syntax-error

I am trying to run react project on AWS ec2 server.
so I deployed node server and built react project in Ec2 instance.
I'm trying to connect between node server and built react project.
I'm using the Nginx server.
This is nginx.conf file content.

```
`# For more information on configuration, see: `#   \* Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/

# \* Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/\*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user \[$time_local\] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    
    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }
    
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

server {
server_name proqureng.com;
root /var/www/client;
index index.html;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/proqureng.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/proqureng.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
listen 80;
listen \[::\]:80;
server_name proqureng.com;

       location / {
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
           proxy_pass https://localhost:5005;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       }

}
server {
listen 80;
listen \[::\]:80;
server_name python.proqureng.com;

       location / {
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
           proxy_pass https://3.11.83.44:5003;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       }

}
server {
listen 80;
server_name admin.proqureng.com;
root /var/www/admin;
index index.html;
}

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }
    
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
    server {
       listen 5001;
       server_name 3.11.83.44;
       root /var/www/admin;
       index index.html;
    }
    server {
       listen 5002;
       server_name 3.11.83.44;
       root /var/www/client;
       index index.html;
    }
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.proqureng.com;
    return 301 $scheme://proqureng.com$request_uri;

}

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.

# 

# server {

# listen       443 ssl http2;

# listen       \[::\]:443 ssl http2;

# server_name  \_;

# root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

# 

# ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";

# ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";

# ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;

# ssl_session_timeout  10m;

# ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;

# ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# 

# # Load configuration files for the default server block.

# include /etc/nginx/default.d/\*.conf;

# 

# error_page 404 /404.html;

# location = /404.html {

# }

# 

# error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

# location = /50x.html {

# }

# }

}\`
```

I got error like that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJKyI.png)

I hope someone solve this error.
thanks

I'd like to run front end and back end on AWS Ec2.
I want to fix this issue.